Where does the ground go or use a different fixture thoughts?
I’m replacing track lighting in my garage there are two, one track at both ends of the garage and they run on the same switch.
When I took it all down it’s in a plastic housing and had one hot one neutral and ground that all attached to the track lighting.
I wanted to do a simple keyless ceiling lamp holder but that only has a spot for a hot and neutral no ground unless I get a keyless ceiling lamp holder with added outlet on the side that does have a ground which I could do. Please some info helps.
To break it down light switch controls two track lights in garage one on each end. Take down track light hot neutral ground. Housing is plastic so no way to ground there. The simple light bulb holder has no ground unless I change it out for the ones that also have the added plus on the side.  What can I do or what should I do?
End result is I’m trying to plug in my led lights I put up because the current connections to hard wires are really short. If there’s a better way to hard wire it please let me know!


This was already a lightbulb socket that’s what I’m trying to install and so in the garage but garage fixtures aren’t a pull chain run on light switch and has a ground that attached to the old fixture since the Box is plastic.


Hi,
Please don't add extra info as "answers" - instead [edit] your question

Plugged in stuff that is made mostly with plastic does not usually use ground.  You keep the house wire grounds connected together and to metal(box), but can usually place a wire nut on loose/unused ground wires or remove ground wire going to plastic.

Light fixtures are not always required to have a connection for ground, especially if the fixture is made from plastic.
If you have ground coming into the box, if the box is metal, connect the ground to that. If the box is plastic, connect all available ground wires together, or if there is only one, cap it off.
I would not advise you to remove the ground wire, in case the next fixture you want to put up does require ground.
